# How to read data from unknown input type (filestream or stdin) C

Tags: c

I wanted to know how to read data from an unknown source of input, meaning I don't know if the user is going to just type a sentence or is he going to give me some text file.
I've tried using `fscanf` since I've read it is meant for unformatted input type
this is my code, Im suppose to get some type of input(file or just a sentence `(echo bla bla bla)` and `"int"` and print only the `"int"` first words. The program should be used for piping meaning the command would look like that :
There are 2 ways to ways of using the program:

```
1.echo "blabla" | myprog 2  (number of words to print)
2.cat input.txt | myprog 2  (number of words to print)
```

The problematic line is line 16, I tried using `fscanf`
Thanks!

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <ctype.h>
  3 #include <string.h>
  4 #include <stdlib.h>
  5
  6
  7 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  8    char *words[32];
  9    int numofwords = atoi(argv[2]);
 10    int i=0;
 11    int len;
 12    char *word = malloc (32 * sizeof(char));
 13    char c;
 14   while (i<=numofwords){
 15    if ((c = getc (argv[1])) != EOF){
 16         fscanf(argv[1],"%s",&word);
 17         len = strlen (word);
 18         words[i] = malloc ((len+1) * sizeof(char));
 19         i++
 20    }
 21    printf(words[i]);
 22   }
 23   return 0;
 24 }
 25
```

Comment: 1) You forgot to copy the string. 2) `while (i<numofwords){...}` 3) `while (i=0; i < numofwords; i++){` saves you the `i++` line 4) `if ((c = getc (argv[1])) != EOF){` is nonsense. 5) maybe try fopen() and fgets() instead?

Comment: `getc(argv[1])` is incorrect.  If your first argument is expected to be an integer, try something like: `int limit; limit = strtoul( argc[1], NULL, 0 );`

Comment: The problem is I dont know if ill get a file or console input, so fopen is not good, anf fscanf requiers a size no?

Comment: @user1108310 Your question is not very much clear..Explain bit more with an example. What do you mean by this `echo blabla/input.txt | myprog 2  (number of words to print)` **?** ...

Comment: edited, hope this helps understanding

Comment: @user1108310 check my answer.. let me know if I can help you more. you were missing some basic concepts that why I written a new code.

Comment: "I've tried using fscanf since I've read it is meant for unformatted input type" It's the opposite. All scanf functions are meant for formatted input. The 'f' in the scanf stands for "formatted".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be I am correctly understood your need.

I am not rectifying your code but writing my own.

Below is simple code that read from console: code: `main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc!=2){
        printf("\n wrong number of argument\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int numofwords = atoi(argv[1]);
    char buffer[128];

    //printf("%d\n",numofwords);

    while(numofwords--){
        scanf("%s",buffer);
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How does it works:

```
~$ gcc  main.c -o main
```

execute:

```
:~$ ./main 

wrong number of argument
:~$ ./main 2
grijesh
grijesh
yourname        
yourname
:~$
```

I hope its understood to you. the program simply read (scan) from console and print out to console. The while loop runs for number of time you pass on command line input.

Now, A text file `dumy.txt` a input file:

```
:~$ cat dumy.txt
yourname
myname
hisname
hername
:~$
```

Now see what you want to achieve through you code:

```
:~$ cat dumy.txt | ./main 2
yourname
myname
:~$
```

If you want to pass through `echo` :

```
:~$ echo $'one\ntwo\nthree' | ./main 2
one
two
:~$
```

*Is this you want?*

If yes:

What you miss understood that:

**[your code]**

(*mistake 1,2*)
Your fsacnf is  wrong in two ways:

```
fscanf(argv[1],"%s",&word);
```

- First argument is `argv[1]` is `char*` that is wrong you need to pass `FILE*` type. As explained in Mr. Oli Charlesworth's answer.
- Second you still need to read from `stdin`. `|` operator redirects the output from first command to second command.

(*mistake 3, 4, 5, 6*)
By sending `echo "blabla"` you are just sending a single sting you need to do something like I did (*I added \n in echo string for new line also my echo string start with `$` so it not print as raw string*). echo so that you can read from code according to second argument that is `argv[1]` not `argv[2]`.  So in your code following line is wrong too.

```
int numofwords = atoi(argv[2]);
```

I corrected this line in my code.

and `i` is initialised  to zero `i = 0` , in while loop condition is `<=`, I think it should be `<`.

(*mistake 7*)
The way you run your code is wrong `echo "blabla" | myprog 2` your program not know as `mygrog` you have to pass complete path. like I did `./main`, `./` means current directory.

this just my view about your question. Read also the answer in comment given by Mr.  William Pursell.

Let me know if you have other doubts.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand what was my problem, I thought did if iwrite cat input.txt|myprog 2, then input.txt is considered to be one of "argv[]". that is wring right? another question for you is why exectly fscnaf is wrong? because argv[1] is an INT?

Comment: @user1108310 If you want to use fscanf do like `fscanf(stdin,"%s",&word);` (2) No, `argv[1]` is not `int`, its `char*` type.

Comment: @user1108310 Very important: In this command `cat input.txt | myprog 2` ,  `cat` command out put is redirected to `myprog` and you would run it `./myprog` that reads from `stdin` .

Comment: I understand know, but what if for example say argv[2] is some text? what should I do? can I use fscanf?

Comment: Yes `argv[]` is text type is `char*` . But two things I wants to say. (1) you are pass exactly two arguments ` myprog 2` first program name that is `argv[0]`= `"myprog"` and second `argv[2] = "2"`  (2) is `argv[]` already available in a buffer. (3) yes you can use fscanf as `fscanf(stdin,"%s",&word);`

Comment: If I do fscanf(stdin,"%s",&word); then im scaning the stdin. But lets say my commend is this : "myprog ILoveC", then argv[1]=ILoveC, but how do I use fscanf to get it? Thanks!

Comment: @user1108310 that is the point I written in (2) in my above comment. that Argument second that is `ILoveC` is already in buffer `argv[1]` so there is no need to fscanf to get it. `argv[]` is a variable string just like `word[]` in your code. you can just do like `char* x  = argv[1]` now `"ILoveC` is pointed by `x` and you can `printf("%s",x);`..Give it a try!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but I think it may be "how do I treat a file input and console input the same?".

Are you aware that `stdin` (the standard input) is already a `FILE *`?  So that means you can pass it as the first argument to `fscanf`, just like a "normal" file:

```
FILE *normal_file = fopen(...);

// Read from normal file
fscanf(normal_file, "%d", &x);
// Read from stdin
fscanf(stdin, "%d", &y);
```

Comment: Yes much better way of expressing what I want to acheive. I understand that stdin is apointer but if I write file.txt would it just read it as if it was a normal string instead of opening the file?

Comment: So Ill to do 2 scans? there is no way to handle both cases with one command?

Answer (score 3):

An alternate choice would be pass the file name as an argument instead.

1. echo "blabla" | myprog 2  (number of words to print)
2. myprog 2 input.txt (number of words to print)

Then you'd:

- if argc == 1, then proceed normally and process stdin (stdin is a FILE*) with fgetc, or another alternate f* method.
- If argc == 2, then get the filename from argv[1], use fopen(filename) to get a FILE* and process it.

Otherwise, you would do what Oli said and get the first word, then either fopen and pass to your processing function, or fseek(stdin, SEEK_SET, 0) then pass stdin to your processing function.

Comment: Thanks this was very clear, when I do "cat input.txt" it acctually turns the text inside input to be like stdin right?

Comment: yes, the cat will output the contents of the file to stdout, which you can pipe into stdin of another program.