# how do i feed printf as input to a C program using a file?

Tags: c, linux

I know you can give input to a C program in linux like this

```
me $ printf "some input" | ./someProgram
```

I want to do the same thing using input from a file, like this

```
me $ myProgram < myFile.txt
```

myProgram has two gets statements that I want to fill w/printfs as input.

```
  printf("...."); fflush(stdout);
  gets(var1);
  printf("...."); fflush(stdout);
  gets(var2);
```

The program behaves as expected when I fill the vars from an input file like this

```
"12345"  //expect to fill var1 w/ 12345 and it does
"12345"  //expect to fill var2 w/ 12345 and it does
```

But the program does not behave as expected when my input file looks like this

```
printf "12345"  //expect to fill var1 w/ 12345 but it does not
printf "12345"  //expect to fill var2 w/ 12345 but it does not
```

Clearly, C is not interpreting the print command in the same was as if I gave the command as input and then piped it into the program.

What's going on? What do I fix? How can I give printf input from a file?

Comment: did you add \n to terminate the lines?

Comment: @akh2103: you may find [my answer helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414883/how-to-read-data-from-unknown-input-type-filestream-or-stdin-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C isn't interpreting any commands at all. When you use `... < file` to redirect `stdin`, the contents of that file become the input to your program - verbatim. So if the file contains

```
"12345"  
"abc"
```

, then `var1` will be `"12345"` (not `12345`) and `var2` will be `"abc"` (not `abc`). Similarly, if the file contains

```
printf "12345"
printf "12345"
```

, then `var1` will be `printf "12345"` and `var2` will be `printf "12345"`.

As I see it, you have two choices: Either you put

```
12345
12345
```

in the file and use `./someProgram < myFile.txt`, or you put

```
printf "12345\n"
printf "12345\n"
```

in the file and use `sh myFile.txt | ./someProgram` (executing the contents of myFile.txt as a shell script).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the trailing newline.

`printf "12345\n"` should work well.