# Read file as input from the command line

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to read a file from the command line passed as input. No not the filename. I'm not expecting the user to input a filename on the command-line, so that I could open it like this : `fopen(argv[1], "r");`.

I am expecting a file like this : `myprogram < file_as_input`. So whatever should go into argv is the contents of the file. How do I do this in C/C++ ?

Comment: Example (with `each` also): [How to read data from unknown input type (filestream or stdin) C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414883/how-to-read-data-from-unknown-input-type-filestream-or-stdin-c/14415292#14415292)

Comment: Mayank: note [`<` on comment line is redirection operator](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/042.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a program is invoked like this `./a.out < file`, the content of the file will be available on the standard input: `stdin`.

That means that you can read this content by reading the standard input.

For example:

- `read(0, buffer, LEN)` would read the from your file.
- `getchar()` would return a char from your file.

Answer (score 3):

On using redirection on the command line, argv does not contain the redirection.

The specified file simply becomes your stdin/cin.

So no need to open it using `fopen` ,just read from the standard input.

Example :

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{

vector <string> v;

copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin),
    istream_iterator<string>(),
    back_inserter(v));

          for(auto x:v)
                cout<<x<<" ";

return 0;
}
```

> test `<input.txt`

**Output**

Contents of input.txt seperated by space